# Unable to Compile program using Boost and Eureqa in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

So I am about to try a simple Eureqa API example in Xcode as shown on:
https://code.google.com/p/eureqa-api/

However as I tried to compile it there seems to be an error in the access.hpp of the boost headers in this line:
...

```
{
    // note: if you get a compile time error here with a
    // message something like:
    // cannot convert parameter 1 from <file type 1> to <file type 2 &>
    // a likely possible cause is that the class T contains a 
    // serialize function - but that serialize function isn't 
    // a template and corresponds to a file type different than
    // the class Archive.  To resolve this, don't include an
    // archive type other than that for which the serialization
    // function is defined!!!
    t.serialize(ar, file_version);
}
```

...
With a message: No member named 'serialize' in 'std::_1::pair'

What should I do in order to fix this?

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and then this error pops out in the utility.hpp: `ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("first", const_cast<typef &>(p.first));
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("second", p.second);`  saying that: No member named 'make_nvp' in namespace 'boost::serialization'

Comment: Aha. I see you did respond. As you have found you need to comment on the answer you respond to. Alternatively/additionally you can use `@JusufAurumMerukh` style explicit addressing (only if it adds value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just want to include the header

```
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
```

which defines the serialization for `std::pair<>`.

**EDIT** After the comment (and arriving home) I've reproduced the problem on linux with boost 1.58. Indeed, editing `eureqa/implementation/connection_impl.h` to include

```
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
```

fixes it:

```
g++ basic_client.cpp \
    -I/home/sehe/custom/boost/ \
    -I../../ \
    -c -o basic_client.o
g++ basic_client.o \
    /home/sehe/custom/boost/stage/lib/libboost_system.a \
    /home/sehe/custom/boost/stage/lib/libboost_serialization.a \
    /home/sehe/custom/boost/stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a \
    /home/sehe/custom/boost/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a \
    -lpthread  \
    -o basic_client
```

---

*The `::_1` is likely an artifact of the library implementation (libc++) using inline namespaces for versioning.*

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and then this error pops out in the utility.hpp: 
`ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("first", const_cast<typef &>(p.first)); 
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("second", p.second);` saying that: No member named 'make_nvp' in namespace 'boost::serialization'

Comment: @JusufAurumMerukh I reproduced and tested the fix. I'm pretty sure you inserted the include(s) in the wrong place. See updated answer

Comment: Ok i see. I used my mac xcode and a lot of this type of error pops-out afterwards: 
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`
I also don't quite understand the g++ codes you write.

Comment: That's just the makefile commands being displayed. I don't write them. I only did `make` in the `examples/basic_client` directory, like the documentation told me. That would also solve your linker errors, because, well, you failed to link the necessary libraries...

Comment: [tag:c++-faq]  has this [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). Only 356 upvotes :)